# Angular ngClick on svg rect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I have several `rects` in an `svg` and I need them to fire off angular click functions.

```
<rect data-ng-click="scrollToAnchor('siteHeader')" fill="#010101" width="501" height="81"></rect>
```

and the function:

```
$scope.scrollToAnchor = function(anchor) {
  $anchorScroll(anchor);
};
```

I know the function itself works because if I call it by itself, outside of one of these clicks, it does what it should do.

Heres an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/31bQh2efVAxzsybjJuIn?p=preview

Comment: It must be something about the way the click events are appended.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for submitting the Plunker. I've not changed anything except correcting the syntax errors in the `<br/>` and it seems to be working. It's scrolling to the 'siteHeader' that has been passed in.

http://plnkr.co/edit/kyEv7IyAXGFRdZjaD4vM?p=preview

Comment: It does, the svg is a scope variable in the same controller as that click event, bound as html.

Comment: Are you able to generate a Punker example and post?

Comment: Added to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of, it is working. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UIeyf9QSzQRQTkWajh38?p=preview):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $anchorScroll) {
  $scope.row = [
    { node: { x: 0, y : 0, name: 'test' } },
    { node: { x: 50, y : 50, name: 'foo' } }
    ];

    $scope.scrollToAnchor = function(anchor){

      $anchorScroll(anchor);
    }

});
```

Scroll down a bit to the rectangle and click on it. It scrolls back to the  tag. Hope this is what you were looking for.